# How can I make the "if" statement for a link to work fine if I want to show it only if it's not the "Index" page

Tags: if-statement, tapestry, tml

In my application,the first page is Index.tml and I have a login form.
The layout for this application has a menu with some links in it and I added another one which is called "Delogheza-te"=Log-out.
What I want is that ,the "log-out link" to be visible only after the user logged-in.
The log-out link should be visible on all pages except "Index.tml".
How can I do that?
I tryed this but it's wrong.

```
<t:if  t:page!="Index">
 <a href="#" t:type="PageLink" t:page="Index">Delogheaza-te</a>
 </t:if>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this situation I like to give the layout component a component parameter, maybe a boolean showLogout, which is true by default but can be set to false in some pages such as the index page.

-- in Layout.java --

```
@Parameter(value="true")
@Property
boolean showLogout;
```

-- in Layout.tml --

```
<t:if test="showLogout">
     (logout link here)
</t:if>
```

-- in Index.tml --

```
<html t:type="layout" showLogout="false">
```

Comment: Your code has meaning, and I understand it but it gives me an error for the line @Parameter(value=true). There is another way to write that line?

Comment: I forgot the quotes. I think @Parameter(value="true") or @Parameter("true") will work, give that a try ,